# wifi adapter problem rtl8723bu created new problem

Tags: drivers, wireless, iwlwifi, wifi-hardware-switch, madwifi

I have installed driver rtl8723bu for poor wifi signal problem. now problem is solved but i am seeing two interfaces for same(only one usb adapter) wifi adapter.

`ifconfig` screenshot:

[image: ifconfig screenshot]

Gnome wifi option:

[image: gui screenshot of gnome wifi option]

Comment: You connection is work properly? If yes it is not a problem, may is the way the driver works or Ubuntu network manager works, it could be possible a virtual interfaces has been created on the top of the physical one.

Comment: Sounds like 'concurrent mode'. Please give a link to the file you downloaded (git?) to compile the driver. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you downloaded the usual driver from the lwfinger git repository. If this is so, please open a terminal and change directories to the location of the files:

```
cd ~/Desktop/rtl8723bu
```

Or wherever you downloaded the file, if not Desktop.

Let's clean up the old driver files:

```
make clean
```

And update the driver with any changes:

```
git pull
```

In the README.md, concurrent mode is explained:

> Concurrent or Non-Concurrent Mode
>
> By default driver operates the hardware as a station AND as an access point *simultaneously*.  This
>   will show two devices when you run the `iwconfig` command.
>
> If you do not want two devices (station and an access point)
>   *simultaneously*, then follow these instructions.
>
> - Step 1: Run the following command in the Linux terminal.  `nano Makefile`
> - Step 2: Find the line that contains `EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_CONCURRENT_MODE` and insert a `#` symbol at the beginning of that line. This comments that line and disables concurrent mode.

Now run:

```
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot.